# rename multiple mp3 filenames from greek to english with bash script

Tags: bash, shell, rename

I have dozens of mp3 files where the filename contains Greek letters. I would like to rename them to "latin only characters" so that the title etc. is displayed correctly on all common playback devices.

It takes a long time to do this manually, so I need your help.
Is there a simple bash script that can do this job?

as example:

I want the script to rename the file from `σαγαπώ.mp3` to `sagapo.mp3`

edit://

I was now able to rename the file name with a python script.

Of:

```
Βασίλης Μπατής - Ζημιά _ Vasilis Mpatis - Zimia _ Official Video Clip HQ 2017.mp3
```

would:

```
Basilis Mpatis - Zimia _ Vasilis Mpatis - Zimia _ Official Video Clip HQ 2017.mp3
```

So far so good, now the question is how do I get rid of all "unnecessary" information from the file name, so that in the end only the `artist` and `title` remain as file names.

This is what the file name should look like at the end.

```
Basilis Mpatis - Zimia.mp3
```

Anyone an idea?

Here is my Python script:

```
import os

# Pfad zum Ordner mit den MP3-Dateien
path = '/home/sakis/mp3'

# Alle MP3-Dateien im Ordner durchlaufen
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith('.mp3'):
        # Aktuellen Dateinamen speichern und in Unicode umwandeln
        old_name = file.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')

        # Dateinamen in zwei Teile trennen
        name, extension = old_name.rsplit('.', 1)

        # Griechische Buchstaben im Dateinamen ersetzen
        new_name = old_name.replace('Ά', 'A').replace('Έ', 'E').replace('Ή', 'H').replace('Ί', 'I').replace('Ό', 'O').replace('Ύ', 'Y').replace('Ώ', 'W').replace('ΐ', 'I').replace('Α', 'A').replace('Β', 'B').replace('Γ', 'G').replace('Δ', 'D').replace('Ε', 'E').replace('Ζ', 'Z').replace('Η', 'H').replace('Θ', 'TH').replace('Ι', 'I').replace('Κ', 'K').replace('Λ', 'L').replace('Μ', 'M').replace('Ν', 'N').replace('Ξ', 'X').replace('Ο', 'O').replace('Π', 'P').replace('Ρ', 'R').replace('Σ', 'S').replace('Τ', 'T').replace('Υ', 'Y').replace('Φ', 'F').replace('Χ', 'X').replace('Ψ', 'PS').replace('Ω', 'O').replace('ά', 'a').replace('έ', 'e').replace('ή', 'i').replace('ί', 'i').replace('ό', 'o').replace('ύ', 'y').replace('ώ', 'w').replace('ϊ', 'i').replace('ϋ', 'u').replace('ό', 'o').replace('α', 'a').replace('β', 'b').replace('γ', 'g').replace('δ', 'd').replace('ε', 'e').replace('ζ', 'z').replace('η', 'i').replace('θ', 'th').replace('ι', 'i').replace('κ', 'k').replace('λ', 'l').replace('μ', 'm').replace('ν', 'n').replace('ξ', 'x').replace('ο', 'o').replace('π', 'p').replace('ρ', 'r').replace('ς', 's').replace('σ', 's').replace('τ', 't').replace('υ', 'y').replace('φ', 'f').replace('χ', 'x').replace('ψ', 'ps').replace('ω', 'o')

        # Alle weiteren Zeichen im Dateinamen entfernen
        name = ''.join(c for c in name if c.isalnum() or c in [' ', '-', '_'])

        # Neuen Dateinamen setzen
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, old_name), os.path.join(path, new_name))

print('Done!')
```

Comment: `perl -CA -MText::Unidecode -e 'rename($_,unidecode($_)) for @ARGV' filenames`

Comment: thanks for the tip, but the translation is not accurate. As an example, the Greek singer "Stamatis Gonidis" is translated as "Stamates Gonides". Original name in Greek is "Σταμάτης Γονίδης". I would also like to create a solution with Linux's own tools, if possible, without having to install additional tools.

Comment: BTW I find the transcription _Stamatis_ more natural (after all, ης is pronounced like "is" in English).

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your own tranlsation table, because nobody can guess how you want to translate the names. Assume that the greek name is stored in variable `greek_name`, something like this could do:

```
english_name=$(tr αβΓγΔδεΖζ... avGgDdeZz... $greek_name)
```

Of course you have to make compromises: Since for instance the letter υ can be pronounced as "i", "f" or as "w" depending on the context, you have to settle for one.

Another problem is that several greek letters are pronounced the same; for instance, Ο and Ω. If you don't manage to map them uniquely, it might happen that two greek file names map to the same english file name. Therefore, when you do the renaming, make sure that you get at least an error message in this case:

```
if ! mv -n "$greek_name" "$english_name"
then
  echo Can not rename "$greek_name", because "$english_name" already exists
fi
```

**UPDATE:**

It's not clear how you would translate i.e. ψ, as the most natural mapping would be to use two charcaters, "ps". You could either use an english letter which has no equivalent in Greek anyway ('c' comes to my mind), or you translate these special cases in a separate step, for instance:

```
# english_name could still contain a ψ because this
# was not handled by `tr`
english_name=${english_name//ψ/ps}
```

You have of course make up your mind whether you want the upper case Ψ being translated into *PS* or *Ps*.

You have not specified how you want to use in translation the English letter *b*. In Greek, this sound is written as νπ, i.e. two Greek letters map to a single English one. If you want to implement this mapping, you have to do it **before** the one-to-one translation done by `tr`, for instance:

```
# Already preprocess νπ before translating the other 
# Greek letters:
greek_name=${greek_name//νπ/b}
greek_name=${greek_name//Ν[πΠ]/B}
```

This reflects the idea that a Greek word starting with Νπ is meant to be a word starting with an upper case letter, and ΝΠ is meant to start an all-upper-case word, both corresponding to an upper-case B in English.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description. Unfortunately, I can't program, so I would be grateful if you could post the complete script for me, so that I can then adapt the individual letters to my needs.

Comment: @sakistech: First of all, every programmer writing a complete program for you, would need at least a precise problem specification. In your case, this would need a definition, how greek characters should be mapped to English characters, and a specification of how the greek file names shouild be obtained. But more importantly, you are asking this in the wrong place: On Stackoverflow programmers (beginners and advanced ones) **discuss** programming problems. To get a complete (non-trivial) program written for you by someone, you could ask [here](https://www.freelance.com/) .

Comment: @sakistech : Having said this: I now see that you updated your question, stating that you have already written a Python program for this task. It just fails in a certain way. This means that (a) you **are** a programmer, who just needs his program fixed, and (b) this is really a **Python** question. I suggest now that you post a new question on this topic, publish the Python code you have, and explain in what respect the outcome is different from what you expect. In this way, the question could be acceptable here at Stackoverflow.